# Electron prepending the application path to my src path in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

I have a bunch of images that are downloaded from a server and saved in the applications `userData` path. In development I can reference these fine in an image element. However once in production, the path is being prepended with the applications path.

So I buuld the path like so:

```
return path.join(app.getPath('appData'), 'MyApp', asset.url);
```

I was originally using:

```
return path.join(app.getPath('userData'), asset.url);
```

This returns: `C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\MyApp\assets\5280.jpeg` which is correct.

When in production, the src says `C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\MyApp\assets\5280.jpeg` but the tooltip says `file:///C:/Users/Dev/AppData/MyApp/app-0.1.1/resources/app/src/C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\MyApp\assets\5280.jpeg`, so it's prepending `file:///C:/Users/Dev/AppData/MyApp/app-0.1.1/resources/app/src/`.

Somewhat at a loss here on how resolve this. Any ideas?